# Parse JSON output in Python using Requests and its sessions

Tags: python, json, parsing

Here I have a rate stream that outputs the following and i'm looking to only print the "bid" price.  Could someone help explain how I can parse the output correctly?  It's driving me crazy!

example = 1.05653

I need the output without quotes or any other markup as well..

JSON

```
{
    "tick": {
        "instrument": "EUR_USD",
        "time": "2015-04-13T14:28:26.123314Z",
        "bid": 1.05653,
        "ask": 1.05669
    }
}
```

My code:

```
import requests
import json

from optparse import OptionParser

def connect_to_stream():
    """
    Environment           <Domain>
    fxTrade               stream-fxtrade.oanda.com
    fxTrade Practice      stream-fxpractice.oanda.com
    sandbox               stream-sandbox.oanda.com
    """

    # Replace the following variables with your personal ones
    domain = 'stream-fxpractice.oanda.com'
    access_token = 'xxxxx'
    account_id = 'xxxxxxxxx'
    instruments = "EUR_USD"

    try:
        s = requests.Session()
        url = "https://" + domain + "/v1/prices"
        headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                   # 'X-Accept-Datetime-Format' : 'unix'
                  }
        params = {'instruments' : instruments, 'accountId' : account_id}
        req = requests.Request('GET', url, headers = headers, params = params)
        pre = req.prepare()
        resp = s.send(pre, stream = True, verify = False)
        return resp
    except Exception as e:
        s.close()
        print "Caught exception when connecting to stream\n" + str(e) 

def demo(displayHeartbeat):
    response = connect_to_stream()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print response.text
        return
    for line in response.iter_lines(1):
        if line:
            try:
                msg = json.loads(line)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                return
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    print line                  

            if displayHeartbeat:
                print line
            else:
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                print line

def main():
    usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-b", "--displayHeartBeat", dest = "verbose", action = "store_true", 
                        help = "Display HeartBeat in streaming data")
    displayHeartbeat = False

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) > 1:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
    if options.verbose:
        displayHeartbeat = True
    demo(displayHeartbeat)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sorry if this is an extremely basic question but I'm not that familiar with python..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The JSON objects may contain line feeds, so you cannot parse each line individually. For streaming purposes you may need to look at another decoder which detects the end of the JSON objects. Or write one yourself; JSON has a simple state model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be pretty easy, I fixed it by replacing the "demo" function with this:

```
def demo(displayHeartbeat):
    response = connect_to_stream()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print response.text
        return
    for line in response.iter_lines(1):
        if line:
            try:
                msg = json.loads(line)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                return

            if displayHeartbeat:
                print line
            else:
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    print msg["tick"]["ask"] - .001
                    instrument = msg["tick"]["instrument"]
                    time = msg["tick"]["time"]
                    bid = msg["tick"]["bid"]
                    ask = msg["tick"]["ask"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
def demo(displayHeartbeat):
    response = connect_to_stream()
    for line in response.iter_lines():
        if line.startswith("        \"bid\"")
            print "bid:"+line.split(":")[1]
```

Comment: I agree, but it is code supplied by oanda to be used with their API so there must be something in there they need..  Thanks for the help though

Comment: Ok now I'm getting this error "Caught exception when converting message into json
Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"  getting somewhere though!

Comment: So I think the issue with iter_content is that you need a fixed chunk size and it would appear that your JSON isn't always a fixed size? I'm gonna edit 1 last time with 1 more attempt and then I give up.

Comment: Thanks Carson, I really appreciate the help.  Ill post when I get it

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the stream line by line attempting to parse each line as JSON. Each line alone is not proper JSON so that's one problem.

I would just regex over each hline you bring in looking for the text "bid: " followed by a decimal number, and return that number as a float. For example:

```
import re

for line in response.iter_lines(1):
    matches = re.findall(r'\"bid\"\:\s(\d*\.\d*)', line)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        print float(matches[0])
```

Comment: I think you are right, however, I cannot get it to work.  I have added the code in a few places and when I get it to run it still outputs the original JSON.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for the help by the way!